# related to j2me visual midlet used in netbeans

Tags: netbeans-6.9

Hi
how do i create a loading screen in j2me project using visual midlet of netbeans6.1

Answer (score 0):

use `SplashScreen` Control, it seems like loading Screen Midlet put some Delay by thread for processing showing like loading

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/loginscreen.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H9AI6ru7R8

Hope it may Helps